# How to pass javascript url parameter in this script through html dom?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to pass url parameter through html dom. This is the javascript i am using

```
<script>
function myFunction(url)
{
setTimeout(function(){window.location.assign(url)},4000);
}
</script>
```

HTML

```
<a href="#" onclick="myFunction(http://stackoverflow.com)"> Click here </a>
```

But its not working. How can i fix this situation ? Thanks for your answers.

Comment: You should try a little more before ask. That's a easy one and understanding it is part of learning how the language works. -1

Comment: I am completely new to javascript thats why i asked

Comment: I realized that, but just asking won't sum to your learning than searching, reading the docs, learning how to understand errors and etc. See [these topics](https://www.google.com/search?newwindow=1&safe=off&site=&source=hp&q=javascript+using+the+console&oq=javascript+using+the+console&gs_l=hp.3..0i22i30l5.1248.4430.0.4555.28.28.0.0.0.0.265.3184.13j11j3.27.0.ernk_timecombined...0...1.1.32.hp..2.26.2919.nNIdnUVi7Hs)(choose according to your fav browser).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use combination of single and double `quotes`, to pass the `url` as string literal. If the url is not enclosed in quotes it is considered as some `variable` and javascript could nod find that.

```
<a href="#" onclick="myFunction('http://stackoverflow.com')"> Click here </a>
```

Answer (score 0):

As @Adil says, you need to pass the argument as string to the function. In the way you are trying, the script is trying to recover the value of the `http://stackoverflow.com` variable.

Answer (score 0):

what @Adil has said is true:

```
<a href="#" onclick="myFunction('http://stackoverflow.com')"> Click here </a>
```

but if you want to pass the url as a parameter do not forget to change your function like this:

```
function myFunction(url)
{
    setTimeout(function(){window.location.assign(encodeURIComponent(url)},4000);
}
```